# Getting the discord voice channel using its id

Tags: discord.py

I had a necessity to connect to a voice channel using its id. After some research, I came across something like this:-

```
channel: discord.channel.VoiceChannel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
```

But I am unable to find a way of getting the channel using its id.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`guild.get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=#discord.Guild.get_channel) method to get a voice channel by id.

```py
voicechannel = guild.get_channel(123456789012345678)
```

If you don't already have the guild, you can get it from the message.

```py
voicechannel = message.guild.get_channel(123456789012345678)
```